# How to specify the folder path for java in Play-With-Docker-Lab?

Tags: java, docker, directory, virtual-machine

Hello guys I have an assignment in which I need to run a `jar` on docker. I need to do the assignment in the sandbox environment labs-play-with-docker (https://labs.play-with-docker.com/). The assignment is to be done by creating a Dockerfile then an image and then run a container. The jar has 3 variables which I want to give a standard value. So what I want is that when I run the container that it starts the jar file with the predestined values for the variables. The jar creates a folder called FOLDERNAME in FOLDERPATH and creates a text document every 10 seconds in which PRINTMESSAGE is written.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

ADD jarName.jar jarName.jar


CMD FOLDERPATH=root FOLDERNAME="arg" PRINTMESSAGE="arg" java -jar jarName.jar
```

We are supposed to base our image on `openjdk:11-jre-slim`. What I finally (!) managed do to was to successfully build the image.
Now whenever I run a container with the command `"docker run <containerName>"`
I get the exception:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Invalid folder path passed.: <folder path> at s04a02.Main.main(Main.java:37)".
```

I simply want the folder path to be set in the root folder of labs-play-with-docker.

So my question is how can I do this? The folder path "~" or "root" or "/root" have not worked for me. When I specify a folder path on my OS then it works but I don't know the folder path for a VM.

It would be great if you could tell me and explain shortly to me which folder path you used and why you used it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, basically what you need is to set your working directory in your container .

In your Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

# destination path is automatically created if it doesn't exist
ADD jarName.jar /usr/src/labs-play-with-docker/jarName.jar

# Set current working directory to desired my_app_directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/labs-play-with-docker.

CMD ["java", "-jar", "jarName.jar"]
```

The `WORKDIR` command is used to define the working directory of a Docker container at any given time, and afterwards any `RUN, CMD, ADD, COPY, or ENTRYPOINT` command will be executed in the specified working directory

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now I understand the role of ADD and WORKDIR and the file path has worked too :)